# Angular 2 structural directive, clear view reference upon non bubbling event triggered by child

Tags: angular

Lets say we are having a list of images we are going to display:

```
<div  *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
    <div *appMaskImageOnError="i"  #mydir>
        <img  [src]="image" alt="" (error)="mydir.remove()">
    </div>   
</div>
```

If there is an error we want to get rid of the whole inner div. How is this possible? How do I get my directive to remove only the faulty image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMaskImageOnError]'
})
export class AppMaskImageOnErrorDirective {
  @Input() appMaskImageOnError: any;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, { remove: () => this.remove() });
  }

  remove() {
    this.vcRef.clear();
  }
}
```

and then your template should look as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
  <div *appMaskImageOnError="i; remove as del">
    <img [src]="image" alt="" (error)="del()">
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tQR5JjzohQF1da7G1jQp?p=preview)**

If you want to keep only one `div` then use `ng-container`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
  <div *appMaskImageOnError="i; remove as del">
    <img [src]="image" alt="" (error)="del()">
  </div>
</ng-container>
```